# C++ How to have a vector of objects depending on template type

Tags: c++, templates, vector, inner-classes

I have a template class C that which should contain a vector with E objects. The E objects in the vector will store the same type as the template is. So if the C object is of type `int` the vector should contain E objects that contain `int`, if C has `double` then E should store a `double` etc. The code looks like this:

```
template<class T> class C {
public:
    class E {
    private:
        T value;    //if C has type int then the events should store int
        std::string description;
    public:
        Event(std::string desc, T val) {
            this->description = desc;
            this->value = val;
        }
    };
    C();
    virtual ~C();

    bool add_e (std::string description);

private:
    T c_value;
    std::vector<E> c_vector; //this should look somewhat like [E<int>, E<int>, E<int>]
};
```

And this compiles, but when I try to add elements to c_vector in the C.cpp file like this:

```
template<class T>
bool C<T>::add_e(std::string description) {
    c_vector.add(E(description, c_value));
}
```

I get the error: 'class std::vector < C< int >::E, std::allocator< C< int >::E > >' has no member named 'add'. What is going on? How can I accomplish to store E objects which stores the same type as the enclosing template class type C?

When I try so search the web I only find information about storing different template types in a vector by for example making E a derived class of an abstract class and then store abstract class pointers in the vector, but I want all of the elements to contain the same type.

Comment: You need to read more about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It has never had any `add` function.

Comment: What about push_back() ??

Comment: Thank you! Too used to Java... I changed to push_back and now it works perfectly

Comment: *Don't* fix the code in the question, because now it looks like you asked "I have this code: <working code goes here>, why doesn't it work?". @burakozgul could write that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JayW Either self answer, or delete your question please. We don't want that kind of posts here actually.

Comment: Your edit made the question non sense now (error mismatches corrected code)...

Comment: Oh come on guys, don’t abuse downvotes. Close the question instead and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `push_back()` from `std::vector`